# run time error 1004 from excel popping up everytime i open the workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am faced with this error, and the issue is highlighted out by Excel. (shown below)

1. [image]
2. [image]

That is all the information I had from Excel.

```
Set IsQuestion = Range("'SAQ Profile'!$B$" & StartRow)   <---------- Issue Highlighted
```

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim StartRow As Integer
    StartRow = 20
    Dim IsQuestion As Range
    Set IsQuestion = Range("'SAQ Profile'!$B$" & StartRow)   <---------- Issue Highlighted
    While IsQuestion.Value <> "finished"
        If (IsQuestion.Value = True) Then
            Dim QuestionId As Range
            Set QuestionId = Range("'SAQ Profile'!G" & StartRow)
            If (QuestionId <> "") Then
                Call CreateSingleSelect(QuestionId, StartRow)
            End If
        End If
        StartRow = StartRow + 1
        Set IsQuestion = Range("'SAQ Profile'!$B$" & StartRow)
    Wend
    Range("C7").Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Dim wSheetName As Worksheet
    For Each wSheetName In Worksheets
        wSheetName.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        Next wSheetName
End Sub
```

and I don't know how to fix, Can anyone assist?

Comment: Pls try `Set IsQuestion = Sheets("SAQ Profile").Range("B" & StartRow)`

Comment: `Range("'SAQ Profile'!$B$" & StartRow) `&`Range("'SAQ Profile'!G" & StartRow)`
The 2 formulas above will be your problem, change them to the following 
`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SAQ Profile").Range ("B" & Startrow)` &`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SAQ Profile").Range ("G" & Startrow)`

Comment: Thanks taller and Sunny, but unfortunately both resulted in a new "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" error. :(